# Header names with underscores ignored in php 5.5.1 / apache 2.4.6

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

After upgrading to php 5.5.1 and apache 2.4.6, checking for certain headers is now broken (specifically, checking for `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`).

Through further testing I noticed that any custom header that contains an underscore is ignored (by this I mean it does not show up in PHP's `$_SERVER` array). So if I add a header named `my-header`, it becomes available as `$_SERVER['HTTP_MY_HEADER']`, but if I try adding a header `my_header`, it's not available in `$_SERVER`.

Comment: Since you are using Apache, do you get the correct headers when using [`apache_request_headers`](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php)

Comment: @FDL yes, I do get correct headers with apache_request_headers

Comment: Should have done the research before posting... This is a documented feature in apache 2.4:
"Translation of headers to environment variables is more strict than before to mitigate some possible cross-site-scripting attacks via header injection. Headers containing invalid characters (including underscores) are now silently dropped." - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_4.html

Comment: Good find, you should add this as an answer and accept it so others can gain from it in the future.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a documented feature in apache 2.4. See [httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_4.html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_4.html)

> Translation of headers to environment variables is more strict than
>   before to mitigate some possible cross-site-scripting attacks via
>   header injection. Headers containing invalid characters (including
>   underscores) are now silently dropped.

Comment: And how do you get around this 'feature'?

Comment: Just replace _ by - : "custom_api_key" --> "custom-api-key"

Comment: If (like me) you're stuck with legacy interfaces that can't be modified, the documentation explains a workaround: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/env.html#fixheader

Comment: Pavle I was crazy looking for the reason I didnt work, you saved my life man, thanks.