# How do I get custom headers with PHP 5.5

Tags: php, curl

Im using PHP 5.5 on WAMP. I ahve a very very simple API. I want to read the request headers from a GET request. I'm printing out all headers:

```
    foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) {
        echo "name is ".$name." and value is ".$value."....";
    }
```

I do the request via curl:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "api_key: hv7Vgd4jsbb" -H "device_id: 63843" http://localhost/schoolspace.me/device_api/project/beaufort
```

As you can see there are 2 custom request headers api_key and device_id. But they do not appear in the output since upgrading to PHP 5.5 (I get Content-type and Accept headers fine).

I've done it like this for years and never had any issues.

How do I get custom headers with PHP 5.5?

Comment: This might be applicable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185366/header-names-with-underscores-ignored-in-php-5-5-1-apache-2-4-6

Comment: Thats it! That's crazy - I have many apps in app stores that send custom headers that use an underscore. Does that mean I have to update them all??? Note: I cannot downgrade PHP on server

Comment: I think the solution is to change the names of your custom headers so they don't include "illegal" characters. Also, it appears as though this is an Apache issue rather than PHP.

Comment: Do they show up in apache_response_headers()? I use that function to get headers and I didn't have a problem when upgrading to php 5.5.

Comment: @kainaw i think you mean apache_request_headers(). And yes, that works. So I'll use that rather than having to change on the app side