# Custon headers not working on php 5.6 - apache 2.4, debian 8 jessie

Tags: php, apache, debian, apache2.4, php-5.6

I just upgraded my debian 7 wheezy to debian 8 jessie. Apache and php were updated accordingly from `apache 2.2.22 to 2.4.10` and from `php 5.4.x to 5.6.9`. Now when sending custom headers with ajax request, they are not present in php. Here is a simple example with `index.php` and `ajax.php` files with the following contents respectively.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(elm, xhr, s){
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('MY_HEADER', 'my_header_value');
                });

                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : 'ajax.php',
                    data : {},
                    error : function() {
                        alert('error');
                    },
                    success : function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php //phpinfo();?>
    </body>
</html>
```

and

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_MY_HEADER'])) {
        echo $_SERVER['HTTP_MY_HEADER'];die;
    }

    print_r($_SERVER);
?>
```

In `$_SERVER` the `HTTP_MY_HEADER` is not present.

I have tried this example in my another server with debian 7 with apache 2.2 and php 5.4 and it works fine - the header is set. But for the upgraded version it does not.

Mod headers is enabled and apache is restarted.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what are these headers ? if it's header with underscore, this difference comme from Apache 2.4 :

[Header names with underscores ignored in php 5.5.1 / apache 2.4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185366/header-names-with-underscores-ignored-in-php-5-5-1-apache-2-4-6)

Comment: cant believe it was just a problem like this, was trying to solve this for a few hours ... thanks a lot