# Getting php code issue in AJAX file upload example at sitepoint

Tags: javascript, php

Can someone please help me to debug the php code in the post at https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-ajax-file-upload/ . PHP script here is no longer able to upload the file.

I tried this with my local server but the file is not uploading in upload folder.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: it is mention there _You can view the demonstration page, however, please note it is hosted on a server without PHP support and the upload will not occur. Therefore, please download the files to examine the code and install it on your own PHP server._ .You should understand it easily

Comment: I tried this on my local server (XAMPP/WAMP) and file is not uploading in upload folder

Comment: ok what are the console error

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not a PHP guy but there was no console error form JS side. It is something to do with PHP code which is not uploading the file in the specified folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial is old.
In file `filedrag.js` there is function `function UploadFile(file) {....}` in that change

`xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);`

to

`xhr.setRequestHeader("X-FILENAME", file.name);`

since underscores are deprecated in later Apache releases, and ignores it, so there is error which is seen in console. For more (refer [Header names with underscores ignored in php 5.5.1 / apache 2.4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18185366/3898339)
 )

After changing it will upload to respective directory